# Authentication for component page by checking whether the user is logged in using angular api

Tags: angular, api, typescript

How to authenticate the package component page? in this the user is logged in by api service file, but even if not logged in and by typing url its navigating to package page. Only when the user is logged in its should go to package page or else it should redirect to login page even url is typed.

### login.component.ts

```js
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router,private ApiService:ApiService) {}
  public user:User = new User();

  login(user:any) {
    this.ApiService
        .loginAdmin(user)
        .subscribe(
         user  => {
            this.router.navigate(['/category']);
       },     
        error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
   }
}

export class User {
  public email:string;
  public password: string;
  public token: string;
}
```

### package.component.ts

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './package.html'
})
export class PackageComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router,private ApiService:ApiService){}
  ngOnInit(){
  this.ApiService
    .package()
    .subscribe(
      user => {
         this.router.navigate(['/package']);
      }),
      error => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
  }
}
```

### api.service.ts

```js
export class ApiService {
constructor (private http: Http) { }

public Auth:any;

loginAdmin(user: Object) {
  return this.http
    .post(urlBase + 'users/adminLogin',user)
    .map(response => {
      var auth = response.json();
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', JSON.stringify(auth.data[0].token));
      localStorage.setItem('userEmail', JSON.stringify(auth.data[0].email));
      localStorage.setItem('userId', JSON.stringify(auth.data[0]._id));
      this.login=true;
      return auth;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || { };
}

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.message || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
  
  package(){
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the ApiService.package implementation is missing in your example. But anyway it is not the right way to do such security check.

You should learn to use route guard ([official guide here](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards))

The main advantage is that you security logic is decoupled from your component and if requirements are not fulfilled your component will not even be instantiated.